# Issue importing model for a different app withing the same django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django project with two different apps in it. There is a users and campaign app. I am working with the campaign models and I want to import a users model to link as a foreign key. I can successfully import a campaign model into the users model and set it as foriegn key. I cant do it the other way around. I will be attaching some peices of code below.

THE IMPORT STATEMENTS - campaign models python file:

```
from django.db import models

from users.models import Founder
from .choices import CATEGORY_CHOICES, PLATFORM_CHOICES, PROGRESS_CHOICES, SIZE_CHOICES
```

the campaing model that needs access to the users model being imported:

```
class Update(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Detail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    impact = models.TextField()
    founder = models.ForeignKey(Founder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.campaign.name + ' update'
```

This is the model I am trying to import:

```
class Founder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Credential, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Detail, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    commitment = models.TextField(null=True)
    since_month = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=MONTH_CHOICES)
    since_year = models.IntegerField()
    portfolio = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    relation = models.TextField()
    known = models.IntegerField()
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + '-' + self.campaign.name
```

Here is the file structure I have setup right now.

[image]

Comment: can you explain more on `I cant do it the other way around. `

Comment: Why do you need foreign keys in both directions?